# What is the average accuracy of horizontalaccuracy in CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

When the accuracy was tracked in a real device, the highest seen was 1414 and the lowest found was 5. However it is not stable and keep varying.

What should be the average so that an acceptable deviation be coded, beyond which the location update may be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Most Apple devices use *'assisted GPS'* which means that it firsts uses the cellular network to track the position, before the actual GPS kicks in (perhaps minutes later). That's why the initial accuracy can be very poor, if the GPS is not activated when you request the location.